# How to use python api get request

Tags: python, api, get, urllib, urllib2

I use the below function to get data from the web , but failed. I wonder whether `urllib.quote` use incorrect

i have used `urllib.urlencode(xx)` but it show `not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object`

and my request data is:

```
[{"Keys": "SV_cY1tKhYiocNluHb", "Details": [{"id2": "PK_2gl9xtYKX7TJi29"}], "language": "EN", "id": "535985"}]
```

Anyone can help. Thanks a lot !!!

```
###This Funcation call API Post Data
def CallApi(apilink, indata):
    token = gettoken()
    data = json.dumps(indata, ensure_ascii=False)
    print(data)
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % (token)}
    proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({})
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)
    DataForGet=urllib.quote(data)
    NewUrl= apilink + "?" + DataForGet
    request = urllib2.Request(NewUrl, headers=headers)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request, timeout=300)
    message = response.read()
    print(message)
```

Error:

> the err message below: File "/opt/freeware/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1198, in do_open raise URLError(err)

Comment: and the err message below:    File "/opt/freeware/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1198, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)

Comment: And If you try to use import requests?

Comment: this is old server and python version 2.7 and cant install requests model

Comment: Requests officially supports Python 2.7 & 3.4–3.7

Comment: But need pip install right? Current our server not allow install model

Comment: I have read some about this error...I will recommend you first check if this is error is caused from Python or Network... https://superuser.com/questions/202370/why-urllib2-doesnt-work-for-me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could see the comment of **urlencode**

> Encode a dict or sequence of two-element tuples into a URL query string

So you could choose removing the outer `[]`

```
{"Keys": "SV_cY1tKhYiocNluHb", "Details": [{"id2": "PK_2gl9xtYKX7TJi29"}], "language": "EN", "id": "535985"}
```

Or use a two-element tuple

```
(('Keys', 'SV_cY1tKhYiocNluHb'), ('Details', [{...}]...)
```

Demo

```
>>> import urllib
>>> s = {"Keys": "SV_cY1tKhYiocNluHb", "Details": [{"id2": "PK_2gl9xtYKX7TJi29"}], "language": "EN", "id": "535985"}
>>> urllib.urlencode(s)
'Keys=SV_cY1tKhYiocNluHb&Details=%5B%7B%27id2%27%3A+%27PK_2gl9xtYKX7TJi29%27%7D%5D&language=EN&id=535985'
>>>
```

Comment: i have removed the outer [] ,but still  URLError(err) , and at the same time the data is array so removed outer [] seems not satify .